# Why does assigning to part of a string (using array syntax) not throw an error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Given a string, you can get a character by index using array syntax, like so:

```
>>> str = "hello"
"hello"
>>> str[2] // gets the third character of the string
"l"
```

Strings are immutable in JavaScript, so it's impossible to change them in place:

```
>>> str[2] = "j"
"j"
>>> str
"hello"
```

What I don't understand is, why doesn't this throw an exception?

Comment: Just a note, strings are not arrays. They are a one of the 5 primitive types in JavaScript. Moreover, they are not assigned by reference, but by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the way that you expect.  Check out the following in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4w7Hk/

```
str = "hello";
alert(str[2]);
// "l"
str[2] = "j";
alert(str[2]);
// still "l", not "j"
```

Note that this does not throw any warning or error. But you can get it to throw by using strict mode.

See the following with strict mode on

```
"use strict";

var str = "hello";
alert(str[2]);
// "l"
try{
    str[2] = "j";
    // we never get here
    alert(str[2]);
}
catch(e){
    alert(e.message);
    // 2 is read-only
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment to str[2] fails, but it still returns the value, which gets assigned to 'a'.

That seems pretty clear cut.

[edit] As for why it doesn't return an error, that's probably implementation-dependent.  I've noticed Javascript is more prone to just not doing something silently rather than giving an explicit error.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question . . . ?